# Edit and create HTML file using Python

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, python-import

I am currently working on an assignment for creating an HTML file using python. I understand how to read an HTML file into python and  then edit and save it.

```
table_file = open('abhi.html', 'w')
table_file.write('<!DOCTYPE html><html><body>')
table_file.close()
```

The problem with the above piece is it's just replacing the whole HTML file and putting the string inside write(). How can I edit the file and the same time keep it's content intact. I mean, writing something like this, but inside the **body tags**

```
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="img/tor.png">
```

I need the link to automatically go in between the opening and closing body tags.

Comment: I dn't know if I understand your assignment scope correctly, but I would advise you take a look at BeautifulSoup for this (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

Comment: Mainly because with the approach you're taking, you can just put the whole html in a single doc string and then just write it into a file. Nothing programmatic about it

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You probably want to [read up on BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
import bs4

# load the file
with open("existing_file.html") as inf:
    txt = inf.read()
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(txt)

# create new link
new_link = soup.new_tag("link", rel="icon", type="image/png", href="img/tor.png")
# insert it into the document
soup.head.append(new_link)

# save the file again
with open("existing_file.html", "w") as outf:
    outf.write(str(soup))
```

Given a file like

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <p>What's up, Doc?</p>
</body>
</html>
```

this produces

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<link href="img/tor.png" rel="icon" type="image/png"/></head>
<body>
<p>What's up, Doc?</p>
</body>
</html>
```

(note: it has munched the whitespace, but gotten the html structure correct).

Comment: Try using outf.write(bs4.BeautifulSoup.prettify(soup)) it fixes the whitespace issue

Was going to put up a separate answer but credit where credit is due.

Read the BS documentation on attributes and changing tag names - super helpful