# Update the values of 4 values in a HTML file using Python

Tags: python, html, web

I have a HTML code that has 4 values, `h6,h7,h8` and `h9`. My goal is to have a Python code that updates those values in the HTML using 4 variables in the python code. Something like (how I think it would look) `html.h6 = variable1`. So when I refresh the page opened locally, the new values are there. Is there a easy and well documented way to do this?

Comment: Look into beautifulsoup, you can load the html, edit it with beautifulsoup and then save the file again. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35355225/edit-and-create-html-file-using-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<html><body>
<h6>variable 1</h6>
<h8>variable 3</h8>  
</body></html>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

h6 = soup.find_all('h6') # all elements that match your filters
h8 = soup.find('h8') # return one element

# replace all h6 tags string it with the the string of your choice:
for tag in h6:
    tag.string.replace_with('new variable value')

h8.string.replace_with('new text')

print str(soup)

#Output
<html><body>
<h6>new variable value</h6>
<h8>new text</h8>
</body></html>py
```